# Is there a way to get an oauth2 "access_token" to Google API with my JSON credential file?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-cloud-api-gateway

I'm trying for long hours to make a simple HTTP Post request for one of google's REST API.
(Specifically the image text predict one, using model imagetext@001)

I'm supposed to send an "access_token" in the header of the HTTP POST,
but unfortunately, I can't manage to get a hold of my access_token.

In all of their guides, they use this command to obtain it:
"gcloud auth print-access-token"
But, I'm running the HTTP POST locally, not from the google cloud console,
so I can't run this command.

I have a JSON credential file but it doesn't contain an access token.

I've searched for so long into how to obtain the access_token.
The few places I've found, for example this:
[How can I get an oauth2 access_token using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719540/how-can-i-get-an-oauth2-access-token-using-python)

Didn't work for me.
This is what I got in return:

```
{
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
  "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: client_credentials"
}
```

I'm sure that I'm missing something. What is it?